# If two functions go to infinity at zero, does the difference go to zero?

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{ x\to0} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{ x\to0} g(x) = \infty$, then $\lim_{ x\to0} [f(x) − g(x)] = 0$. 
 True or False??

Comment: almost always false

Comment: indeed a good example of why you should not even use the notaion lim<whatever> "equals" <infintiy>

Comment: @george: It's even better to keep this extremely useful notation, and simply learn how to do arithmetic *correctly* with extended real numbers.

Comment: @george as Hurkyl says, $\infty-\infty$ is not defined in extended real numbers, so there is no problem with using this.

Answer (score 11):

False!
 
For example 
$$
f(x)=\frac2{x}, \ g(x)=\frac1{x}.
$$

Answer (score 8):

**No**

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{3m}{\sin^2x}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{3m}{x^2}$
$$\lim_{x\to0}[f(x)-g(x)]\neq0 \quad,\forall m\in \mathbb N\cap\{m\ge 1\}$$

**Edit**:$$\lim_{x\to0}[f(x)-g(x)]=\lim_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac{3m}{\sin^2x} -\dfrac{3m}{x^2}\right]=\lim_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac{mx^4}{x^4}\right]$$

Comment: Why do you have the condition $m\geq 4$ (or even $m\in\mathbb N$)?

Comment: @Jonas Meyer : because $$\lim_{x\to0}[f(x)-g(x)]=\lim_{x\to0}[\dfrac{3m}{\sin^2x} -\dfrac{3m}{x^2}]=\lim_{x\to0}[\dfrac{mx^4}{x^4}]$$

Comment: Maisam: I don't understand how your comment is relevant to my question.  I see that you have now replaced the condition $m\geq 4$ with $m\geq 1$, but it doesn't matter whether $m$ is a natural number.  The limit is $m$, so the only condition needed to not get $0$ is $m\neq 0$.  I like the example.

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}
{\rm f}\left(x\right) = {1 \over x}\,,
\quad
{\rm g}\left(x\right) = {1 \over x}\,;
& \qquad\qquad{\large\mbox{( TRUE )}}
\\[3mm]
{\rm f}\left(x\right) = {2 \over x}\,,
\quad
{\rm g}\left(x\right) = {1 \over x}\,;
& \qquad\qquad{\large\mbox{( FALSE )}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

False. Let $f(x)=\dfrac1{x^2}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac1{x^2} + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Blurry, as the examples have shown you, the essense here is that you cannot work with infinity as if it is a number. Infinity is an entity with which you cannot calculate in a normal fashion as with ordinary numbers. Just like saying infinity divided by infinity is equal to 1. Very often that is not true either. In case of infinity - infinity, usually making one term (most of the time fractional) out of them is the way to go.
Feel free to post an actual limit problem and we will help you.